# append writing to a csv file using fast-csv

Tags: node.js, csv, express

My function below reads the accounts.csv, however, i want to be able to write in it.  Every time i do a fs.createWriteStream, it overrides the entire file and replaces it. Here is my code.  I want to append results

```
let stream = fs.createReadStream("accounts.csv");

fast
    .fromStream(stream, {headers : ["Account",
        "OrgName", "Contact1", "Contact2", "AddrLine1",
        "AddrLine2", "City", "State", "ZipPostal", "Country",
        "AccountType", "ACCTTYPE", "Partner", "PTRDATE", "LSTCONTD",
        "LSTGIFTDT", "LSTGIFTAmt"]})
    .on("data", function(data){
      var orgName = data
      console.log(data);
    })
    .on("end", function(){
      console.log("done");
    });


let ws = fs.createWriteStream('accounts.csv');

fast.
    write([

        {r: "r1", s:"s1"}

    ], {headers:true})
        .pipe(ws);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default flag for `fs.createWriteStream` is `w`, which will open the file for writing, creating it if it doesn't exist or truncate it if it does.

You need to use `a` flag, which opens the file for appending.

```
let ws = fs.createWriteStream('accounts.csv', { flags: 'a' });
```

Have in mind, that you should probably wait until the file is read, or append before reading.

Comment: So the flag “a” sort of prepares the file to be appended?  Could you elaborate on your comment about waiting for the file to be read or append before reading please?

Comment: Yes, the `a` flag prepares the file for appending, without truncating. It also creates the file if it doesn't exist. Due to race conditions, is not good to read & write to the file at the same time, I doubt you need to do that, so just write first & read later, or read & write. Not at the same time.

Comment: Use `flags` instead of `flag` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags

Comment: In my case, it appends to last row in csv using your logic

Answer (score 6):

```
let ws = fs.createWriteStream('accounts.csv', { flags: 'a' });
```

flag keyword may be old now. Documentation mentions that it must 'flags'.

[fs.createWriteStream(path, [options])](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/fs.html#fs.createWriteStream)